# How to convert single column list to a table?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a subset data (all in one column):

```
Click to select Starcom
Starcom
Marketing and Advertising
Greater Chicago Area
5001-10,000 employees
View accountSaved
Saved Leads (0)
Click to select R/GA
R/GA
Marketing and Advertising
Greater New York City Area
1001-5000 employees
View accountSaved
Saved Leads (0)
Click to select McCann
McCann
Marketing and Advertising
United States
10,001+ employees
View accountSaved
Saved Leads (0)
Click to select DDB
DDB
Marketing and Advertising
Greater New York City Area
10,001+ employees
View accountSaved
Saved Leads (0)
```

I would like to create a table as such out of it:

```
+---------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| Starcom | Marketing and Advertising | Greater Chicago Area       | 5001-10,000 employees |
| R/GA    | Marketing and Advertising | Greater New York City Area | 1001-5000 employees   |
| McCann  | Marketing and Advertising | United States              | 10,001+ employees     |
| DDB     | Marketing and Advertising | Greater New York City Area | 10,001+ employees     |
+---------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
```

As you can see, I only need the first four rows and then it skips three rows.

So far I have been trying to understand how to do this but can't seem to crack it... been trying to work with `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` functions so far to no avail.

This is a handy thing to know how to do, since some data pastes in this format.

Here is [my example spreadsheet URL](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14AONIjWIA7U4OU1x0OyPc-v1My-cqXxx2FLSwMF93Os/edit#gid=43906390).

Comment: Whoops sorry should be now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data is in ColumnA, please try in B2, and copied from there across three further columns to the right and then the set of four down to suit:

```
=offset(indirect("A"&2+7*(row()-2)),column()-2,)
```

[OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)
[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)
[ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
[COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Modified it to work for each column. :)